# Prove there are at least two periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anyone comment on the following ODE problem? Thank you.

Given a 2-d system in polar coordinates:
$$\dot{r}=r+r^{5}-r^{3}(1+\sin^{2}\theta)$$
$$\dot{\theta}=1$$

Prove that there are at least two nonconstant periodic solutions to this system.

It's easy to prove that there is a noncostant periodic solution using Poincare-Bendixson theorem, but I don't know how to prove the existantce of two nonconstant periodic solutions.

Comment: My guess (not sure if correct): if a spiral one way is a solution, then maybe the same spiral in the opposite direction will also be a solution...

Comment: Yeah, if $(r(t), \theta(t))$ is nonconstant, periodic, and solves the system, then $(r(t), \theta(t) + \pi)$ (aka $(-r(t), \theta(t))$, if you allow negative "$r$"'s in your polar coordinates) also has these properties.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes this is the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice question.  But it appears $\dot r \ge r + r^5 - 2 r^3 = r (1 - r^2)^2 \ge 0$.  So $r$ should go straight to infinity, shouldn't it?  Then how come there is any periodic solution?